# protractor performing keyboard shortkeys with multiple keys

Tags: javascript, protractor

In my application I have menu items and they can be selected using shortcut keys exp: ALT + 1 and this will add a box on the canvas. [image: menu items image]
So if I select either ALT+1, or ALT+2 then the appropriate box will be added on to the canvas [image: using shorcut keys]
In protractor I used various ways and none of them are working
For ex:

```
**method 1**
var plot = element(by.css("deliverable-free-form")); //this is the canvas main body
await plot.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.ALT, "1"));

**method 2**
await browser.actions().keyDown(protractor.Key.ALT).sendKeys('1').keyUp(protractor.Key.ALT);

**method 3**
await addActionBtn.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.ALT, "1")); //addActionBtn is the + button element shown in the above image

**method 4**
browser.actions.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ALT, '1').perform();
```

None of them are working they are throwing some errors like unsupported sendkeystoactivate or WebElement is not intractable and etc.

Is there any other option I can use

Answer (score 0):

As I can see some of your examples are not valid syntax.

Try this:

```
await browser.actions().keyDown(protractor.Key.ALT).sendKeys('1').perform()
```

Comment: I am getting following error when I do that UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: UnsupportedOperationError: sendKeysToActiveElement